# Table refresh after parameter pass to query, ODBC refresh

Tags: vba, postgresql, excel, odbc

I have a table which is populated by an ODBC connection to a PostgreSQL database. The query for this connection has a parameter which is connected to the value of a cell in the worksheet. After the query runs and refreshes the table, I'd like to copy the data set over to a new worksheet, appending the new data set each time the table refreshes. The problem is that the VBA loop I've created does not pause long enough for the table to refresh each time that I increment the parameter. I've tried refreshing the connection in my script and then using 'doevents' to have Excel catch up. Doesn't work. What happens is that the VBA runs the first query and then simply copies the resulting data set over the requisite number of times to satisfy the loop. It doesn't refresh the data each time in between. Thus I get a worksheet with the first iteration of data copied 5 or 6 times, etc.

Here's my script:

```
   Sub auto_increment()

   Dim i As Integer
   Dim d As Integer
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim r As Integer

   Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Competitiveness Summary_any date")
   d = wb.Sheets("data").Range("AS2").Value

   With wb
        For i = 1 To d
        .Sheets("data").Range("AQ4").Formula = "=workday(AQ2," & i & ",Holidays!D1:D8)"
        .Worksheets("data").Select
        ThisWorkbook.Connections("query from Tigris_fulfillment5").Refresh
         DoEvents

   r = .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       .Sheets("data").Range("Table_ExternalData_1").Copy
       .Sheets("Sheet2").Select
       .Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste

   Next i

   End With

   End Sub
```

the variable 'd' represents the number of business days between two dates. I want to increment my parameter cell by the number of business days. All in all, I'm attempting to create a flat file of old data which occurred between two dates. The present query is designed only to return data for one day at a time.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off "Enable Background Refresh" on the connection properties tab and remove the `DoEvents` line.

> [Select this check box to run the query in the background. Clear this check box to run the query while you wait. Running a query in the background enables you to use Excel while the query runs.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/connection-properties-HA010342299.aspx)

You want to **not** use Excel while the query runs. You want Excel to "stop" until the query is finished, so that when you do `Refresh` your code waits.